# Can't connect to team projects after upgrading vs 2012 to update 3

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I have recently upgraded my visual studio from 2012 update 1 to update 3.
Since the upgrade, the team explorer is showing an empty offline home page. Pressing the "Configure Team Projects" on the team explorer's connect page doesn't do anything.

I tried to repair, uninstall and install and to delete the team explorer cache folder but it didn't help.

On the same machine, i have visual studio 2010 installed which works fine.
Any suggestions?