# Cannot connect to Team Foundation Server in Visual Studio 2012 after update 4

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I installed Visual Studio 2012 Update 4 (downloaded from [MS download center](http://www.microsoft.com/fr-fr/download/details.aspx?id=39305)) and lost the connection to Team Foundation Server from Team Explorer. Before that, I was connected right at VS2012 startup. It is not the case anymore and I cannot connect to Team Foundation Server from any entry in VS (Team menu or Team explorer window).
For instance, nothing happens when I click this link:
[image: Team explorer - Disconnected - Update 4]
No modal error window, no indication of an error occuring in windows event viewer or in VS ActivityLog file in roaming directory, so I assume that there was no error.

I tried these and it changed nothing :

- Repair VS2012 from Windows configuration panel
- Install Team Explorer for Microsoft Visual Studio 2012
  based on this blog post: [Connecting to TFS](http://blog.jessehouwing.nl/2013/10/connecting-to-tfs-from-any-version-of.html#tfs2012)
- Restore my system from the restoration point of VS2012 update 4. I got this error at restart :
  An unspecified error occured during system restore : (Visual Studio 2012 Update 4 (KB2707250)). additional data : 0x80070005.
- Install VS Update 4 in system admin mode but the result was the same (corrupted VS install)

The only working part left of VS was the source control explorer. Appart from starting and using source control explorer, VS is unusable. e.g. when I started a web application using VS development server, I got an error message saying that my VS installation was probably corrupted. The only way around was to uninstall and reinstall VS. Some of my co workers have installed Update 4 and do not experience the same issue. But [this Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18311422/cant-connect-to-team-projects-after-upgrading-vs-2012-to-update-3) is about the same bug.
Team explorer window is very different **without** Update 4.
[image: Team explorer - Disconnected]

From event viewer, I see errors which all have the same pattern. Their occuring time match my attempts to install VS 2012 Update 4
Here are their data (I have filtered and removed duplicates)

- .NET Runtime Optimization Service (clr_optimization_v4.0.30319_64) - 1>Failed to compile: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\TF.exe . Error code = 0x80131f07
- .NET Runtime Optimization Service (clr_optimization_v4.0.30319_64) -   Failed to compile: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\bin\x64\aspnet_merge.exe . Error code = 0x800700d8
- .NET Runtime Optimization Service (clr_optimization_v4.0.30319_64) - 1>Failed to compile: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\WinMDExp.exe . Error code = 0x80131f07
- .NET Runtime Optimization Service (clr_optimization_v4.0.30319_64) - 1>Failed to compile: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\SecAnnotate.exe . Error code = 0x80131f07
- .NET Runtime Optimization Service (clr_optimization_v4.0.30319_32) -   Failed to compile: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Blend\Microsoft.Expression.Blend.WwaClientPS.dll because of the following error: The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131018).
- .NET Runtime Optimization Service (clr_optimization_v4.0.30319_32) -   Failed to compile: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Blend\Microsoft.Expression.Blend.WwaClientHost.dll because of the following error: The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131018).
- .NET Runtime Optimization Service (clr_optimization_v4.0.30319_32) -   Failed to compile: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Blend\Microsoft.Expression.Blend.WwaClient.dll because of the following error: The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131018).

---

Here is an export of my corrupted VS2012 installation info :
Microsoft Visual Studio Premium 2012
Version 11.0.61030.0 Q11REL
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.5.51209

Installed Version: Premium

Team Explorer for Visual Studio 2012   04941-004-0043007-02023
Microsoft Team Explorer for Visual Studio 2012

Visual Basic 2012   04941-004-0043007-02023
Microsoft Visual Basic 2012

Visual C# 2012   04941-004-0043007-02023
Microsoft Visual C# 2012

Visual C++ 2012   04941-004-0043007-02023
Microsoft Visual C++ 2012

Visual F# 2012   04941-004-0043007-02023
Microsoft Visual F# 2012

Visual Studio 2012 Code Analysis Spell Checker   04941-004-0043007-02023
Microsoft® Visual Studio® 2012 Code Analysis Spell Checker

Portions of International CorrectSpell™ spelling correction system © 1993 by Lernout & Hauspie Speech Products N.V. All rights reserved.

The American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, Third Edition Copyright © 1992 Houghton Mifflin Company. Electronic version licensed from Lernout & Hauspie Speech Products N.V. All rights reserved.

Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio   11.2.0.3.20
Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio Copyright (c) 2005, 2012

PreEmptive Analytics Visualizer   1.0
Microsoft Visual Studio extension to visualize aggregated summaries from the PreEmptive Analytics product.

SQL Server Data Tools   11.1.20627.00
Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools

Comment: Just so I'm clear: it sounds like *everything* is hosed (not just Team Explorer) and VS is telling you to uninstall completely and then reinstall.  Did you try that?

Comment: Hello Edward. I don't know what you mean by hosted. Everything is located on my system. Yes I reinstalled completely but I don't have Update 4 and it might be the cause of many issues I have with VS 2012. Appart from trying to install Update 4 each time my system is updated (windows update), hopping it will work, I don't know what to do.

Comment: Sorry for the euphemism:  *hosed* (no 't'), as in "broken".  I don't understand the sequence of events.  What's your *current* state: do you have VS 2012 (without Update 4) working? Or is it *not* working also? VS 2012 works fine *unless* you install Update 4? This *seems* like a job for product support.

Comment: after update 4, almost everything in VS was broken. I uninstalled and installed VS, it was the only way to get it work again.

Answer (score 0):

You need to click the configure team projects link.

Comment: Nothing works in team explorer. I tried to install it from a separate source http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=30656 but it changed nothing.

Comment: what happens when you click the Configure Team Projects link?

Comment: Thank you @Dylan. I edited, added info and restructured my question.

Comment: Hello @Dylan. I don't remember exactly what happens when I click the Configure Team Projects link. But I assume it led to a broken 'connect to team foundation server'.

Answer (score 0):

Check your proxy settings from your browser. We generally get this issue when proxy activated. For example fiddler changes proxy settings but sometimes after closing,  fiddler does not deactivate proxy again and we face with TFS connection problem.